# How to compile cpp in linux based on caffe

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, g++, caffe

I get a cpp about visualize-features function.
I want to compile it,but there are some errors.
I move the visualize_features.cpp to CAFFE_ROOT/build/tools/ and use the below command: 
shell command:

```
    g++ -v visualize_features.cpp -o visualize_features
```

visualize_feature.cpp:

```
    // Copyright 2013 Yangqing Jia
    //
    // This is a simple script that allows one to quickly test a network whose
    // structure is specified by text format protocol buffers, and whose         parameter
    // are loaded from a pre-trained network.
    // Usage:
    //    test_net net_proto pretrained_net_proto iterations [CPU/GPU]

    #include <cuda_runtime.h>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <vector>
    #include <utility>
    #include "caffe/caffe.hpp"
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h>
    #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

    using std::make_pair;
    using std::pair;
    using namespace caffe;  // NOLINT(build/namespaces)
    using namespace std;

    vector<string> fileNames;
char * filelist;

/*
 * 读入的文件的内容格式类似这样子的：全局id 类名_所在类的id.jpg
0 一步裙_0.jpg
1 一步裙_1.jpg
2 一步裙_10.jpg

 */
void readFile()
{
    if(fileNames.empty())
    {
        ifstream read(filelist);
        //"/home/linger/linger/testfile/test_attachment/image_filename"
        // "/home/linger/imdata/test_files_collar.txt"
        //  "/home/linger/linger/testfile/testfilename"
        if(read.is_open())
        {
            while(!read.eof())
            {
                string name;
                int id;
                read>>id>>name;
                fileNames.push_back(name);
            }
        }
    }
}

/*
 * 根据图片id获取类名
 */
string getClassNameById(int id)
{
    readFile();
    int index = fileNames[id].find_last_of('_') ;
    return fileNames[id].substr(0, index);
}



void writeBatch(const float* data,int num,int channels,int width,int height,int startID,const char*dir)
{
    for(int id = 0;id<num;id++)
    {
        for(int channel=0;channel<channels;channel++)
        {
            cv::Mat mat(height,width, CV_8UC1);//高宽
            vector<vector<float> > vec;
            vec.resize(height);
            float max = -1;
            float min = 999999;
            for(int row=0;row<height;row++)
            {
                vec[row].resize(width);
                for(int col=0;col<width;col++)
                {
                    vec[row][col] =
                            data[id*channels*width*height+channel*width*height+row*width+col];
                    if(max<vec[row][col])
                    {
                        max = vec[row][col];
                    }
                    if(min>vec[row][col])
                    {
                        min = vec[row][col];
                    }


                }
            }

            for(int row=0;row<height;row++)
            {
                for(int col=0;col<width;col++)
                {
                    vec[row][col] = 255*((float)(vec[row][col]-min))/(max-min);
                    uchar& img = mat.at<uchar>(row,col);
                    img= vec[row][col];

                }
            }
            char filename[100];
            string label = getClassNameById(startID+id);
            string file_reg =dir;
            file_reg+="%s%05d_%05d.png";
            snprintf(filename, 100, file_reg.c_str(), label.c_str(),startID+id,channel);
            //printf("%s\n",filename);
            cv::imwrite(filename, mat);
        }

    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  if (argc < 4)
  {
    LOG(ERROR) << "visualize_features.bin net_proto pretrained_net_proto iterations "
        << "[CPU/GPU] img_list_file dstdir laydepth";
    return 0;
  }
  /*

  //visualize_features.bin /home/linger/linger/caffe-action/caffee-ext/Caffe_MM/prototxt/triplet/triplet_test_simple.prototxt /home/linger/linger/caffe-action/caffee-ext/Caffe_MM/snapshorts/_iter_100000 8 GPU /home/linger/linger/testfile/test_attachment/image_filename /home/linger/linger/testfile/innerproduct/ 6

  */

  filelist = argv[5];
  cudaSetDevice(0);
  //Caffe::set_phase(Caffe::TEST);
  //Phase phase = TEST;
  if (argc == 5 && strcmp(argv[4], "GPU") == 0)
  {
    LOG(ERROR) << "Using GPU";
    Caffe::set_mode(Caffe::GPU);
  }
  else
  {
    LOG(ERROR) << "Using CPU";
    Caffe::set_mode(Caffe::CPU);
  }

  NetParameter test_net_param;
  ReadProtoFromTextFile(argv[1], &test_net_param);
  //Net<float> caffe_test_net(&test_net_param,TEST);
  shared_ptr<Net<float> > caffe_test_net;
  caffe_test_net.reset(new Net<float>(argv[1],TEST));
  NetParameter trained_net_param;
  ReadProtoFromBinaryFile(argv[2], &trained_net_param);
  caffe_test_net->CopyTrainedLayersFrom(argv[2]);

  int total_iter = atoi(argv[3]);
  LOG(ERROR) << "Running " << total_iter << " Iterations.";

  double test_accuracy = 0;
  vector<Blob<float>*> dummy_blob_input_vec;

  int startID = 0;
  int nums;
  int dims;
  int batchsize = test_net_param.layers(0).layer().batchsize();

  int laynum = caffe_test_net->bottom_vecs().size();
  printf("num of layers:%d\n",laynum);

  for (int i = 0; i < total_iter; ++i)
  {
    const vector<Blob<float>*>& result =
        caffe_test_net->Forward(dummy_blob_input_vec);

    int laydepth = atoi(argv[7]);

    Blob<float>* features = (*(caffe_test_net->bottom_vecs().begin()+laydepth))[0];//调整第几层即可

    nums = features->num();
    dims= features->count()/features->num();

    int num = features->num();
    int channels = features->channels();
    int width = features->width();
    int height = features->height();
    printf("channels:%d,width:%d,height:%d\n",channels,width,height);
    writeBatch(features->cpu_data(),num,channels,width,height,startID,argv[6]);
    startID += nums;

  }

  return 0;
}
```

errors:

```
weilam@linux:~/soft/caffe-master/tools$ g++ -v visualize_features.cpp -o visualize_features
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'visualize_features' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1plus -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE visualize_features.cpp -quiet -dumpbase visualize_features.cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase visualize_features -version -fstack-protector -Wformat -Wformat-security -o /tmp/ccDLiCXS.s
GNU C++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) version 4.8.4 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.4, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2-p3, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include
 /home/weilam/soft/caffe-master/include
 /home/weilam/soft/caffe-master/distribute/include
 /usr/local/cuda/include
 .
 /usr/include/c++/4.8
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8
 /usr/include/c++/4.8/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
End of search list.
GNU C++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) version 4.8.4 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.4, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2-p3, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 83f8d9bb238019ed17000f1b7e141e5a
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'visualize_features' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v --64 -o /tmp/cctbPuju.o /tmp/ccDLiCXS.s
GNU assembler version 2.24 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'visualize_features' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/collect2 --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -z relro -o visualize_features /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../.. /tmp/cctbPuju.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/tmp/cctbPuju.o: In function `writeBatch(float const*, int, int, int, int, int, char const*)':
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0x6d8): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0x724): undefined reference to `cv::imwrite(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
/tmp/cctbPuju.o: In function `main':
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0x8e7): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::LogMessage(char const*, int, int)'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0x8f6): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0x91f): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0x945): undefined reference to `cudaSetDevice'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0x98b): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::LogMessage(char const*, int, int)'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0x99a): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0x9b6): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0x9e0): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::LogMessage(char const*, int, int)'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0x9ef): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0xa0b): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0xa24): undefined reference to `caffe::NetParameter::NetParameter()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0xa44): undefined reference to `caffe::ReadProtoFromTextFile(char const*, google::protobuf::Message*)'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0xab2): undefined reference to `caffe::Net<float>::Net(std::string const&, caffe::Phase, caffe::Net<float> const*)'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0xaf1): undefined reference to `caffe::NetParameter::NetParameter()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0xb11): undefined reference to `caffe::ReadProtoFromBinaryFile(char const*, google::protobuf::Message*)'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0xb68): undefined reference to `caffe::Net<float>::CopyTrainedLayersFrom(std::string)'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0xbc0): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::LogMessage(char const*, int, int)'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0xbcf): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0xc08): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0xcc8): undefined reference to `caffe::Net<float>::Forward(std::vector<caffe::Blob<float>*, std::allocator<caffe::Blob<float>*> > const&, float*)'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0xe3c): undefined reference to `caffe::Blob<float>::cpu_data() const'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0xeb5): undefined reference to `caffe::NetParameter::~NetParameter()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0xed3): undefined reference to `caffe::NetParameter::~NetParameter()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0xeec): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0xf09): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0xf26): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0xfa3): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0xfcb): undefined reference to `caffe::NetParameter::~NetParameter()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0xff3): undefined reference to `caffe::NetParameter::~NetParameter()'
/tmp/cctbPuju.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0x104a): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0x1056): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text+0x1062): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/cctbPuju.o: In function `caffe::Caffe::set_mode(caffe::Caffe::Brew)':
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe5Caffe8set_modeENS0_4BrewE[_ZN5caffe5Caffe8set_modeENS0_4BrewE]+0xc): undefined reference to `caffe::Caffe::Get()'
/tmp/cctbPuju.o: In function `caffe::V1LayerParameter::layer() const':
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK5caffe16V1LayerParameter5layerEv[_ZNK5caffe16V1LayerParameter5layerEv]+0x28): undefined reference to `caffe::V1LayerParameter::default_instance_'
/tmp/cctbPuju.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x39): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
/tmp/cctbPuju.o: In function `cv::Mat::create(int, int, int)':
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat6createEiii[_ZN2cv3Mat6createEiii]+0x8e): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int)'
/tmp/cctbPuju.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x47): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
/tmp/cctbPuju.o: In function `std::string* google::MakeCheckOpString<int, int>(int const&, int const&, char const*)':
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x24): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::CheckOpMessageBuilder(char const*)'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x4b): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::ForVar2()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x66): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::NewString()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x75): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::~CheckOpMessageBuilder()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x89): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::~CheckOpMessageBuilder()'
/tmp/cctbPuju.o: In function `google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<caffe::V1LayerParameter>::TypeHandler::Type const& google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPtrFieldBase::Get<google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<caffe::V1LayerParameter>::TypeHandler>(int) const':
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK6google8protobuf8internal20RepeatedPtrFieldBase3GetINS0_16RepeatedPtrFieldIN5caffe16V1LayerParameterEE11TypeHandlerEEERKNT_4TypeEi[_ZNK6google8protobuf8internal20RepeatedPtrFieldBase3GetINS0_16RepeatedPtrFieldIN5caffe16V1LayerParameterEE11TypeHandlerEEERKNT_4TypeEi]+0x45): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::LogMessage(google::protobuf::LogLevel, char const*, int)'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK6google8protobuf8internal20RepeatedPtrFieldBase3GetINS0_16RepeatedPtrFieldIN5caffe16V1LayerParameterEE11TypeHandlerEEERKNT_4TypeEi[_ZNK6google8protobuf8internal20RepeatedPtrFieldBase3GetINS0_16RepeatedPtrFieldIN5caffe16V1LayerParameterEE11TypeHandlerEEERKNT_4TypeEi]+0x5b): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::operator<<(char const*)'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK6google8protobuf8internal20RepeatedPtrFieldBase3GetINS0_16RepeatedPtrFieldIN5caffe16V1LayerParameterEE11TypeHandlerEEERKNT_4TypeEi[_ZNK6google8protobuf8internal20RepeatedPtrFieldBase3GetINS0_16RepeatedPtrFieldIN5caffe16V1LayerParameterEE11TypeHandlerEEERKNT_4TypeEi]+0x73): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::LogFinisher::operator=(google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage&)'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK6google8protobuf8internal20RepeatedPtrFieldBase3GetINS0_16RepeatedPtrFieldIN5caffe16V1LayerParameterEE11TypeHandlerEEERKNT_4TypeEi[_ZNK6google8protobuf8internal20RepeatedPtrFieldBase3GetINS0_16RepeatedPtrFieldIN5caffe16V1LayerParameterEE11TypeHandlerEEERKNT_4TypeEi]+0x87): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK6google8protobuf8internal20RepeatedPtrFieldBase3GetINS0_16RepeatedPtrFieldIN5caffe16V1LayerParameterEE11TypeHandlerEEERKNT_4TypeEi[_ZNK6google8protobuf8internal20RepeatedPtrFieldBase3GetINS0_16RepeatedPtrFieldIN5caffe16V1LayerParameterEE11TypeHandlerEEERKNT_4TypeEi]+0xc2): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
/tmp/cctbPuju.o: In function `caffe::Blob<float>::LegacyShape(int) const':
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi[_ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi]+0x74): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int, google::CheckOpString const&)'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi[_ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi]+0x80): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi[_ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi]+0x99): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi[_ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi]+0xf8): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int, google::CheckOpString const&)'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi[_ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi]+0x104): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi[_ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi]+0x110): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi[_ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi]+0x16f): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int, google::CheckOpString const&)'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi[_ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi]+0x17b): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi[_ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi]+0x187): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi[_ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi]+0x1e1): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi[_ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi]+0x1ed): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi[_ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE11LegacyShapeEi]+0x1f9): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
/tmp/cctbPuju.o: In function `caffe::Blob<float>::CanonicalAxisIndex(int) const':
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE18CanonicalAxisIndexEi[_ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE18CanonicalAxisIndexEi]+0x9b): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int, google::CheckOpString const&)'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE18CanonicalAxisIndexEi[_ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE18CanonicalAxisIndexEi]+0xa7): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE18CanonicalAxisIndexEi[_ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE18CanonicalAxisIndexEi]+0x100): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE18CanonicalAxisIndexEi[_ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE18CanonicalAxisIndexEi]+0x18d): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int, google::CheckOpString const&)'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE18CanonicalAxisIndexEi[_ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE18CanonicalAxisIndexEi]+0x199): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE18CanonicalAxisIndexEi[_ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE18CanonicalAxisIndexEi]+0x1f2): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE18CanonicalAxisIndexEi[_ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE18CanonicalAxisIndexEi]+0x21c): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
visualize_features.cpp:(.text._ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE18CanonicalAxisIndexEi[_ZNK5caffe4BlobIfE18CanonicalAxisIndexEi]+0x242): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

[part of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9wyK.jpg)

Comment: Please post error messages as verbatim text instead of a screenshot.

Comment: you have `undefined references` because the compiler does not see libraries that you are referring to. `-L/path/to/library/` during linking

Comment: Thank you, but I am not clear about what you mean. Is the path of cpp right?Or should I compile all caffe with the cpp file?

Answer (score 0):

As your source code is present in the `tools` folder of `caffe-master`, you could create an executable by executing the regular make command of `caffe` and the executable named `visualize_features.bin` should be present in `build/tools` folder. This is the easiest way for you.

The current build command that you use is so incomplete, the include folders of various dependencies and the path to various libraries are not mentioned. I think you will have to learn on how to write a `Makefile`.

Comment: Thank you, you mean I should edit the `Makefile` of `caffe` and compile all , so a`'.bin` file will be built in `caffe-master/buld/tools` folder?

Comment: If the cpp file is present in the caffe-master/tools folder, there is no need to edit the Makefile even!